# What defines a well-received question?

Tags: support

From the perspective of badges, I was idly wondering what exactly defines a "well-received" question?

Perhaps the more important question is where this information exists? Is it buried in some code somewhere or is there a nice repository somewhere? Or is it, perhaps, deliberately kept vague to prevent people from gaming the system?

Answer (score 3):

From [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) (even though it's in a question, it still appears to be the official definition that other, related posts point towards):

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0. If you ask at least one well-received question in a UTC day and none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed, you get one more day of credit toward the badge. Whenever the badge criteria is checked, previous asking days are re-evaluated so that there's an incentive to fix downvoted and/or closed questions. The no-deleted-questions criteria is to prevent people from asking several questions at once and deleting any that aren't upvoted or answered to ask another day. (Though this is a losing strategy in the long run.)